# Is there a way to see why I am not seeing any events when I try to use an Ingress with GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following ingress...

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: core-ingress
  namespace: earth
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "core-proxy-static-ip"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: core-ingress
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: core-proxy-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

I have used `kubectl exec` to make sure the service itself is running and listening on port 80 so I know `core-proxy-service` is working. When I try to install the ingress it never gets and IP and the events show nothings...

```
Name:             core-ingress
Namespace:        earth
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.109.128.78:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   core-proxy-service:80 (10.109.128.132:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: core-proxy-static-ip
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:       <none>
```

Since there are no events I figure something must have happened and that is why I am not getting an IP but how would I be able to debug to figure out what?

```
NAMESPACE   NAME           CLASS          HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
earth       core-ingress   core-ingress   *                 80      3m33s
```

### Update

If I revert back to

```
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: core-proxy-service
      port:
        number: 80
```

Everything works what am I missing?

Comment: is your `ingressClassName:` core-ingress ? or you just added randomly ? default nginx ingress class name is `nginx` if you are using the ingress controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myservicea
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "core-proxy-static-ip"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: core-proxy-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Ref doc : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/